# How do I open the android emulator's terminal window?

Tags: android, android-emulator, terminal, android-logcat

In order to enable logging for medailytics plug in, I need to enter this into the emulator's terminal

```
adb shell

setprop log.tag.MMT DEBUG
```

Unfortunatly I don't have a clue how to open the terminal and the developer resource didn't seem to mention the subject.

Also I won't be surprised if anyone tells me that there are in fact 150 more steps in this task because the medialytics documentation is really very poor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Windows, it's called the Command Prompt and can be found in your Start menu.

On OS X, it's called the Terminal and can be found in your Apple menu.

On Linux, it's called the Terminal...and if you're on Linux and don't know where that is, may $DEITY have mercy on your soul.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu OS and working with Titanium(Appcelerator), when I install App on emulator from it, Titanium shows a small console down there in Titanium Window only. Is there any way that I can get the same output on a terminal full screen separate from inbuilt one. Thanks in advance....

Comment: On Windows I tried Command Prompt but got "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command...". In this case you also need to add the adb directory to your environment variables. That is, your PATH environment variable must contain <path-to-android-sdks>\platform-tools

Answer (score 5):

You need to ensure 'adb' is installed on your machine (Windows/Linux/Mac).
Follow the steps mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) for configuring your android device and readying 'adb'.
You can try *`adb devices`* to confirm you have the setup ready.
Then find your terminal/command prompt as per your machine OS for running 'adb shell' and next 'setprop' commands!

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

ADB could be in either one of those two locations:

```
~/android-sdk-linux/tools
~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

This is considering you already have the Android SDK installed.

You can run adb from that directory.
Alternatively you can add the path variable to your .bashrc file to run it from anywhere:

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

[or other text editor you prefer]

Then add the following:

```
#AndroidDev PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

If you have adb located elsewhere but don't know where it is, then this could help:

```
locate adb | grep bin
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK

Answer (score 0):

ALT + F1 - open the terminal window
ALT + F7 - close the terminal window

Tested on Android 4.3